# If the element belongs to an array Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get data from Firestore, but in `where()` function I would like to do something like this :

```
firebase.firestore().collection('event')
    .where('sport', 'is in the', some_filter_array)
```

Can I do such a things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IN query, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
    .where('sport', 'in', [a, b, c])
```